# How to implement "speech bubble" in IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA and would like to create a "speech bubble" like in the following screenshot. I've found out how to show notifications but they are different from the notification below.

Are there any examples of this notification type?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To show such a popup, use `ToolWindowManager.getInstance(project).notifyByBalloon()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `VcsNotifier.java` if you like to know how it works in `git4idea` plugin.

Here is an example of notification action, but you can use this code anywhere if you have access to `project`:

**NotificationExample.java**

```
public class NotificationExample extends AnAction {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
        Project project = e.getProject();
        ServiceManager.getService(project, NotificationExample.class).notify(project);
    }

    private void notify(Project project) {
        NotificationGroup notificationGroup = NotificationGroup.toolWindowGroup(
                "IdMessages", ChangesViewContentManager.TOOLWINDOW_ID);

        Notification notification = notificationGroup.createNotification("Title", "Message", NotificationType.INFORMATION, null);
        notification.notify(project);
    }
}
```

**plugin.xml**

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <projectService serviceImplementation="your.package.NotificationExample"/>
</extensions>
```